# Class 'app\controllers\Userinfo' not found

Tags: yii2, yii

Имеется модель CabinetForm с классами

```
class Products extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'products'; 
    }
}
class Characteristics extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'characteristics_sv';

    }
}
class Userinfo extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';

    }
}
```

И в контроллере

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\CabinetForm;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function actionCabinet()
    {

       $user_info = Userinfo::find()->where(['id'=>Yii::$app->user->id])->asArray()->one();
        return $this->render('cabinet', compact('user_info'));


    }
}
```

В итоге ошибка "Class 'app\controllers\Userinfo' not found"
и так всегда, как бы я не менял название класса и т.д. 
А если поменять имя таблицы в классе "Products" то всё работает нормально

Comment: Добрый вечер. А зачем Вы свалили всё в одну кучу? Надо делать одну модель на одну таблицу. То есть одна модель для Products, вторая для Characteristics, третья для Userinfo и четвёртая модель для CabinetForm. И что у Вас с namespace-ами?

Answer (score 0):

Вы в контроллере не импортировали класс Userinfo, и автолоадер пытается его найти в том же пространстве имен что и ваш контроллер